# SQL Server 2016 - Get NULL values from a table using a Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, stored-procedures, refactoring-databases

I am trying to use a stored procedure called `GetCompanies` and a parameter called `@ShowCompaniesWithoutClients` in order to show all companies (from a table called `Company`) where the `Client` column is `NULL` or empty (`''`).

At the moment the solution I found is make an `IF/ELSE` statement where validate `IF @ShowCompaniesWithoutClients=1` I order to

```
SELECT *  
FROM [Company] 
WHERE [Client] IS NULL OR [Client] = ''
```

Otherwise, select all columns (without restrictions).

Can anyone help me refactoring this solution replacing it with a solution where I don't need to `SELECT` statement twice?

Disclaimer: this is just an example of real application, which I have around 20 columns and many more parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so `@ShowCompaniesWithoutClients as bit` can have 3 possible values , 0 , 1 and null.
0 and 1 is clear but when you pass @ShowCompaniesWithoutClients = null means everything should be returned, here is how you can do it :

```
SELECT * 
FROM [Company] 
WHERE  (ISNULL([Client],'') = ''  and @ShowCompaniesWithoutClients  = 1)
    OR (ISNULL([Client],'') <> '' and @ShowCompaniesWithoutClients  = 0)
    OR (@ShowCompaniesWithoutClients IS NULL)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this it just what I needed!